# "Panel" granger test with shared model coefficients

Tags: panel-data, regression-coefficients, model, granger-causality

My question concerns ways to implement a Granger causality model for panel data. The [standard panel granger test](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1801700412) (Dumitrescu/Hurlin (2012)) for N units and T time steps essentially carries out N separate individual granger tests, and computes a test statistic that is the average of the individual test statistics. My concern is that the model coefficients can be different between each unit.

I'm interested in coming up with a *general* model of the effect of X on Y. The effect should  be fairly similar across all units. The standard panel Granger methodology does not seem to handle this.

Is there a known solution to this problem? I am using time-series data, so the idea of using time-lags of X to predict Y is the appeal of the Granger test.

If not, I am thinking of just putting all my panel data into one model. Then the coefficients will be the same across all units, and we can Wald-test whether the coefficients of X are significantly different from 0 as normal. Does this idea make sense?

Comment: I might not get your question correctly, but: If you don't want to allow for N separate time series estimations in the panel Granger test, why don't you go with the original Granger test (that involves a Wald test), i.e., just disrecard the panel structure of the data?

Comment: The issue is that there are still many distinct units in the data, and each unit has two time series (X and Y). However, X/Y shouldn't affect each other across units - i.e. Y for unit 1 is a function of lags of X for unit 1, but not of X for unit 2. 

I'm not sure how the original Granger test would handle multivariate data like this.